# Postgres connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Tags: database, postgresql, macos, homebrew

I am running MacOS 10.14.1 (absolutely new to MacOS), I am unable to run `psql` command installed through `brew`, I get the following error, would love some help:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Solutions I have tried

1. `brew services start` service already running
2. `brew services stop postgresql, brew services start postgresql` still same error
3. `brew remove postgres, brew install postgres, psql` still same error
4. `brew unlink postgresql && brew link postgresql` still same error
5. `rm -f /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` my `/usr/local/var/` does not contain a `postgres/` folder

One more thing to note, when I `brew install postgres` I get a warning:

```
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall postgresql`
```

running `brew postinstall postgresql` gives the same warning.

Hopefully provided enough information to go by, happy to provide more.

Comment: Have you tried `brew update` ? That fixes a lot of issues when brew has some out of date modules. `brew doctor` will also solve some issues. If no luck, `brew config` and paste the results so we can see what version you are running and status.

Comment: Sure have tried `brew update` and `brew doctor` (would love to know what these do - feel free to drop a reference site) ... the output of my `brew config` is below (I notice the last line being `Xcode: N/A` I remember reading something about this...

Comment: HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.8.3
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 4021aa80dfbaa369ee357a955c0216f9566133ac
Last commit: 8 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 39e578fe3c0fbde142ea94ba2a9c6184f5aef97e
Core tap last commit: 12 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
CPU: quad-core 64-bit kabylake
Homebrew Ruby: 2.3.7 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
Clang: 10.0 build 1000
Git: 2.19.1 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 10.14.1-x86_64
CLT: 10.1.0.0.1.1539992718
Xcode: N/A

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is that the process is running but the `postmaster.pid` file is missing from `/usr/local/var/postgres/`, so you need to start the process for `Postgres` which creates `postmaster.pid`.

If the process is already running,

Stop it manually using the command below:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast
```

Start it manually using the command below:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

now all should be working just fine.

Comment: Super. It's working for me on Mac.
I need run this before:  brew services stop postgresql

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Answer (score -2):

I just hit this with an existing brew install of 12.1.

```
brew uninstall postgresql
brew install postgresql
```

This fixed it. Also took me from 12.1 to 12.3.